# Is it possible to get TLSv 1.1 to work with Coldfusion 6.1

Tags: jvm, coldfusion-6, tls1.1

We have a legacy system that runs on Coldfusion 6.1 with JVM 1.6.0 build 24. It appears that TLSv 1.1 was added in build 111. Is it possible to get Coldfusion 6.1 to work with that build (or higher) and what would I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

**TLS 1.1** is only supported in **Java 1.8** on CF10 (Oddly 1.7 and above in CF11)

I dont think CF 6.1 will work properly on higher versions of JDK. You may want to try to upgrade it to 1.8 to see if that helps.

See this Adobe Blog as a starting guide to updating your Java: http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/how-to-change-upgrade-jdk-version-of-coldfusion-server

Also see this: http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2014/12/8/colfusion-jvm-versions-sslv3-tls